# Dynamically create TableAdapter instance

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net server control that is used to sign records. The control calls my stored procedure to sign the record and to call the logging stored procedure. I call the stored procedure in my c# code by creating an instance of the table adapter. I am trying to make it generic so that it can be used for many applications. So I want my code to create an instance of a different table adapter based on a property that I set on the page where the control is used. How can I create a table adapter instance programmatically? 
Here is the existing code. This works for the specific page that I have used this control on.

```
if (lblUniqueKey != null && lblUniqueKey.Text != "")  {
    int keyValue = Convert.ToInt32(lblUniqueKey.Text);
    RCounty.eCa.HSDatasets.EFMTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter QTA =
    new RCounty.eca.HSDatasets.EFMTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter();
    QTA.EFspSupSign(keyValue, UniqueKeyName, empid, empname); }
```

Comment: By doing County.eCa.HSDatasets.EFMTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter QTA = new RCounty.eca.HSDatasets.EFMTableAdapters.QueriesTableAdapter(); you're creating a TableAdapter programmatically. Are you asking how to create a *generic* table adapter so that every application can give their own version of the Table Adapter and your code above works with all of them?

Comment: I want to create an instance of different table adapters based on the value of a property in the control. I tried using activator.createinstance but I am unable to get that to work.

Comment: Can the property be of type "Type"? or is it a string?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to note:

1. I have the strongly typed dataset in another project whose assembly is "DataSetContainer"
2. I load that assembly and the type.
3. I pass in the type to Activator.CreateInstance and that instantiates myTableAdapterInstance, which in my case is: `DataSetContainer.DataSetTableAdapters.ContactsTableAdapter`

   ```
   var myTableAdapterType = Assembly.Load("DataSetContainer").GetType("DataSetContainer.DataSetTableAdapters.ContactsTableAdapter");
   var myTableAdapterInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(myTableAdapterType);

   Response.Write(myTableAdapterInstance.GetType().ToString());
   ```

Hope this answers your question :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I decided to go in a different direction.